# Matrices for linear transformations that operate by multiplying two other matrices from right and left (Serre's linear representations: exercise 2.4)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory

I am currently working on the chapter 2.1 the character of a representation in Serre's linear representations of finite groups.

In the last exercise of the chapter I stumbled upon a linear transformation that works by multiplying two (invertible) matrices from left and right respectively. The exercise goes as follows:

Let $p_1: G \to Gl(V_1)$ and $p_2: G \to Gl(V_2)$ be two linear representations with characters $\chi_1$ and $\chi_2$. Let $W=Hom(V_1,V_2)$, the vector space of linear mappins $f: V_1 \to V_2$. For $s \in G$ and $f \in W$ let $p_s f = p_{2,s} \circ f \circ p_{1,s} ^{-1}$; so $p_{s} f \in W$. Show that this defines a linear representation $p: G \to Gl(W)$ and that its character is $\chi_1 ^* \cdot \chi_2$. This representation is isomorphic to $p_1' \otimes p_2$.

Now to my confusion:
As far as I know every linear transformation can be (uniquely) represented by a transformation Matrix (at least in this case of vector spaces). And as such also $p_s$. This would mean that one would be able to find a Matrix $A$ such that $p_s (f) = A \cdot f$ for each $s \in G$. However this would be somewhat of a contradiction to the fact, that the Dimension of the $Gl(W)$ is $\dim(W)^2$ (since all the vector spaces are supposed to be finite dimensional in the exercise). As such, such a transformation matrix cannot exist and one really needs to multiply two matrices from left and right in order to at least have the same 'degrees of freedom' needed in order to represent the $Gl(W)$.

That's why I think that for the argument or rather rule that every linear transformation can be represented by a transformation Matrix, I'd have to think about $f$ as a vector of some sort with $m+n$ entries (if $dim(V_1)=m$ and $dim(V_2)=n$).

In that case one could find a transformation matrix, correct? (for example by writing all the columns of a matrix as one column from left to right (top to bottom) and then figuring out how the $m \cdot n \times m \cdot n$ Matrix would have to look like

Because if one was able to construct such a matrix one could compute the character which is the only thing I have not been able to solve from the above exercise. However I feel like there is a way more easy approach which I am not seeing.

As one can tell I am getting some things mixed up, so I would be happy about anyone clearing up my mess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The explicit calculation should go like this; hope this will clarify the matter.

Let $e_{i}$ be a basis of $V_{1}$, and $f_{j}$ be a basis of $V_{2}$. For a fixed $s \in G$, write
$$
p_{1,s}^{-1} e_{k} 
=
\sum_{i} a_{ki} e_{i},
\quad
p_{2,s} f_{h} 
=
\sum_{j} b_{hi} f_{j}.
$$
Now $W$ has a basis given by the elements $E_{u, v}$, which map $e_{u}$ to $f_{v}$, and all others $e_{i}$ to zero.

We will have
$$
p_{2, s} \circ E_{u, v} \circ p_{1, s}^{-1} 
=
\sum_{m, n} c_{u v,m n} E_{m n}
$$
for some $c_{u v, m n}$. To compute the trace, we need to compute the diagonal coefficient $c_{u v, u v}$. Now for all $u$ we have
$$
p_{2, s} \circ E_{u, v} \circ p_{1, s}^{-1} 
e_{u} 
= 
\sum_{m, n} c_{u v,m n} E_{m n} e_{u}
= 
\sum_{n} c_{u v, u n} f_{n}
,
$$
so that
$c_{u v, u v}$ will be the coefficient of $f_{v}$ in $p_{2, s} \circ E_{u, v} \circ p_{1, s}^{-1} 
e_{u} $.

We compute this as
\begin{align}
p_{2, s} \circ E_{u, v} \circ p_{1, s}^{-1} e_{u}
&=
p_{2, s} \circ E_{u, v} \sum_{i} a_{ui} e_{i}
\\&=
p_{2, s} a_{uu} f_{v}
\\&=
a_{u u} \sum_{j} b_{v j} f_{j}.
\end{align}
Thus $c_{u v, u v}$  is
$$
a_{u u} b_{v v}.
$$
Now sum over $u, v$.

Comment: You mean in the equation following "For all $u$ we have..."?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Do I understand it correctly that the matrix of the linear transformation $E_{u,v}$ would be full of zeros except a 1 at the u-th column and v-th row?

Comment: To your question concerning the $E_{uv}$, yes.

Comment: To your first comment, there is an index $m, n$ is the first sum, but then $E_{m, n} e_{u}$ is non-zero only when $m = u$, so the index $m$ vanishes in the next two sums.

Comment: Yes, the problem is fixed now, the m,n were to right of the sum when I wrote the comment, now they were moved to the index of the sum

Comment: Oh, yes, sorry about that, it was a misprint (**** happens) that I fixed when I saw it.